# Changing instruction that was misidentified in IDA Pro

Tags: ida, disassembly

I am trying to compare a source code to a disassembled version of a Sega Genesis (68000 processor) game. I ran the binary through IDA Pro 7.7 to disassemble it, and when I was going through the code and comparing it to the source code, I noticed that IDA Pro's disassembler labeled some instructions improperly. Is there a way to manually correct it? As it is, I cannot compile the disassembled code, because an error regarding that instruction will come up.

IDA Pro identifies the code as the following:

```
ROM:00005CA6 013C                                        d0              ; start of messed up disassembly
ROM:00005CA8 00F0 4E75
ROM:00005CAC
ROM:00005CAC                     _1:                                     ; CODE XREF: Findhittype+10↑j
ROM:00005CAC 013C                                        d0
ROM:00005CAE 001E 4E75                           ori.b   #$75,(a6)+ ; 'u' ; end of messed up disassembly
```

The source code shows it as follows:

```
    btst    d0,#%11110000
    rts
.1
    btst    d0,#%00011110
    rts
```

Checking the opcode, it looks like the 68k disassembler does not recognize this instruction.

Here is a description of the BTST instruction:
[image: BTST]
[image: BTST-2]

Is there a way to change this? Thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. By undefining (`u`) and then defining as code (`c`) pieces of code, based on the offset from where you say it wrongly identified it, should theoretically do the job. You can also manually set the instructions, but I don't remember the shortcuts for that (and don't know if the decompiler, for example, would heed those changes).

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the slow reply. I did try this. I did "analyze" when asking after highlighting and pressing C, still displaying wrong. Not sure if there is a bug in the disassembler, it looks like this is not a common way to use the BTST instruction